Possible to pursue physics Phd after applied physics masters?
My goal is to pursue a PhD in physics. I went to a pretty prestigious undergrad in the US, but I didn't stand out very much and I suspect I was mostly average. I did some decent research with one publication and two strong recommendation letters, and an ok GPA of 3.71.
I think what may have significantly hurt me is that I took several years after undergrad before applying for PhD programs. In my first round I was waitlisted at my first choice, but I was admitted into a program that is ~ top 20 nationally (top 10 in my subfield). However after extensively researching the program I decided it would definitely be a bad fit for me, and I decided to try again. In my second round I applied to fewer schools and was not very successful, with only a waitlist that went nowhere.
I am wondering if it would be a good idea to pursue a masters first in a related subject (since there aren't any masters in physics). Specifically, I'm hoping that if I do well in a masters in applied physics (or maybe EE or math) at a top program, then it would benefit me in my PhD applications.
All of my top choice schools have both a physics and an applied physics program which are run by separate departments. My question is, would a masters in AP at one of these schools benefit me in an application to a physics PhD at the same school (or a different one)? Would I have to start the PhD program from scratch or could my years in a masters possibly carry over? Furthermore, do I even have any hope of getting into a top masters program in AP? I know masters are generally less competitive than PhD, but with only one PhD acceptance to my name, I am pretty nervous about it.

I had several colleagues that were just average or even bellow average undergrad students and now they are super successful researchers. You should choose where to apply for a PhD based on the research area and supervisor, university ranking is irrelevant.

Why is it so important to you that you get into a top ranked program that you accept "nothing" as an alternative? You are defeating yourself.

since there aren't any masters in physics --- Did you misstate this? There surely must be more than one hundred universities in the U.S. that offer a masters in physics. I found 5 or 6 in the top 10 hits when googling {masters + degree + physics} -- e.g. San Francisco State University AND Arizona State University AND Texas A & M University

@DaveLRenfro - I think it would be fair to say that at least some top physics programs do not admit students for a masters program. They have PhD admissions, and while they will grant a masters (say after prelims), that is supposed to be on the way to a PhD. (Data point: Princeton).

Or, from Cornell: "Note on Ph.D. and M.S. Degrees
Students admitted to graduate study in physics at Cornell are enrolled in the Doctoral program. There is no Master’s program in Physics. Most students are awarded a Master’s degree at the time of advancement to candidacy, as an in-progress degree."

I think you may be shooting yourself in the foot here by prolonging the process. The further you get from your undergraduate while being away from academia altogether, the worse your prospects look for being able to succeed as a student. It's a difficult mindset to get back into once you are away for a while.
In the US, I would venture to say that within the top 100 ranked physics programs, there are good people doing good work. In the top 25 or so, there are many exceptional PIs, but as you go down into lower ranked program, by virtue of the fact that there are many exceptionally trained scientists coming out of the top programs/groups, and few academic jobs, there are typically at least a few very good researchers in every department. I would focus on just getting into a good group with a supportive PI doing research you find interesting. If you do well, aim for a top-5 postdoc to round out your CV. This is better than waiting for an ideal situation to materialize, which may turn out to be less than ideal once you get there.
